What's wrong with my solution of James stewart 1.7 Q 36?
Question - Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$
My Solution  $|x - 2| < \delta$
$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$
$\frac{\delta}{|2(\delta+2)|}<\epsilon\qquad$  (as $|x - 2| > \delta$ so no mod in numerator)
$\delta < 2\epsilon|\delta+2| \qquad$          (as $\delta$ is positive)
$\delta<\frac{4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}$
But after checking from multiple sources online, the answer is
$\delta \in \min\{1,2\epsilon\}$
Answer Source 1
Answer Source 2

$\Delta+2$ in the denominator is wrong. It should be $2-\Delta$. Also, $\Delta$ is not unique so you need not match the given answer.

First of all note that $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{2x}|x-c|$, as $x \to 2$, means $x$ is approaching to $2$ that is it is inside a neighbourhood of $2$. So we can take $x>0$. Now if $|x - 2| < 1$, then $-1 < x-2 < 1 \iff 1 < x < 3$. So we can write $0<\frac{1}{2x}< \frac{1}{2}$ for all those $x$, which satisfies $|x - 2| < 1$.
Therefore, for all those $x$ we have $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x -2|$. Now $\epsilon>0$ is given, then we have to make $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$. It is sufficient to take $|x - 2| < 2\epsilon$. So if we choose $\delta = \min\{1,2\epsilon\}$, then if $0 < |x -2| < \delta$, then we will get $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$.
Which shows that, $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$.
